# App aparece mensagem "app parou"

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm developing an app using API 14 in Android Studio and using my own phone (moto g5 plus with Android 7.0) and it's okay but when I install it on another device (running with android 5.0 lollipop) the app just does not open. I already generated the signed apk and tb did not solve. Someone help me?

Here's Log:

10-09 11:44:19.054 28206-28206/lcorp.com.temonibus D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-09 11:44:19.074 28206-28206/lcorp.com.temonibus E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: lcorp.com.temonibus, PID: 28206
                                                                     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 101254116 byte allocation with 16772688 free bytes and 51MB until OOM
                                                                         at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
                                                                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
                                                                         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4211)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4085)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3935)
                                                                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)
                                                                         at android.view.View.(View.java:4225)
                                                                         at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:150)
                                                                         at android.widget.ImageButton.(ImageButton.java:85)
                                                                         at android.widget.ImageButton.(ImageButton.java:81)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.(AppCompatImageButton.java:57)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.(AppCompatImageButton.java:53)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:118)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1013)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1072)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                         at lcorp.com.temonibus.TelaInicial.onCreate(TelaInicial.java:22)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: please ask your question in english

Comment: please write your question in english.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Alright then, I'm developing an app using API 14 on Android studio and using my own cell (running 7.0 nougat)) to emulate and make tests and everything looks great but when I get another cell (running an 5.0 lollipop) to install the app it crashes. I already built the signed apk but no working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't provided any log details.
Search your log for "fatal" and look for the main, its the best and the most direct lead to your problem.

But from my experience some common mistakes causing this sort of problems are using the android: nameSpace instead of app: for AppCompat components in your xml files or using non compat components or even methods that are introduced in APIs higher than your minimum SDK.

you're not paying attention to the warnings of the IDE about anything that is either deprecated or is only supported from an specific API and higher.

Never ignore IDE warnings.
They didn't put them there just for decorating purposes.

And in case of your signed Apk, never sign it just using V2 Signature because older versions of android will have problems parsing it